# RegEx Python name matching

Tags: regex

I'm stuck with my regex expression... `\n\s*[\w\säöüÄÖÜß\-?]+\n[\s*^GEB$|\s*^ADR$]`
The expression should match every name within a line break and the leading keywords GEB or ADR. I do not understand why exactly it is not working for me. Here is a link to my [**try**](https://regex101.com/r/BZHb06/1). It does not end with GEB or ADR and so it matches parts of it, which should not be matched. I do not get it.

The problem is, the name could start with e title and can have multiple spaces between the words. Also it is possible for the name to be separated with a '-'.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you just want tomatch a whole line there? See https://regex101.com/r/BZHb06/1, is it what you need to get?

Comment: Probably more what you have in mind [^\s*(\[.\w\s\-?ÄÖÜßäöü\]+?)\s*^\s*(GEB|ADR)](https://regex101.com/r/8ix8aH/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 2nd pair [ ] should be ( ) instead?

I would start with simpler regex like:

```
\n([^\n]+)\n\s*(GEB|ADR)
```

If this is not correct, please update your question with the expected found text parts.

Did you mean something like:

```
   \n\s*([\w\s\.?äöüÄÖÜß\-?]+)\n\s*((GEB|ADR))
```

No need for ^ after a \n, and use ( ) for grouping.